# VM inside host VM cannot see avx cpu flag

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtualization, qemu

I have an `Ubuntu 14.04` server installed on a VM inside VirtualBox.

This VM acts as my host for other VMs.
I ran a Linux based image using qemu inside this host VM.
The host VM has cpu flag avx but the image ran by qemu does not have the avx flag in its /proc/cpuinfo.

I ran it with `--cpu Haswell,+avx,enforce` flags which according to /usr/share/libvirt/cpu_map.xml should have avx already.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Please post the complete run command - you have not even specified what you are using to run it (is it qemu or a libvirt tool?)

Comment: [This](http://superuser.com/a/454814/64511) can be helpful.